# How to make Genymotion device run slower?

Tags: android, genymotion

So I want to keep myself more mindful about making my app faster on less powerful devices. I figure a good way to do this is to build my app on devices with lower specs than the usual high end phones but, this is difficult because I like to use Genymotion. Therefore, how can I configure genymotion to run at lower speeds than it normally does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346109/how-to-reduce-the-amount-of-ram-genymotion-uses)

you need to

1. Open VirtualBox and select emulator
2. Go to setting, then go to system tab
3. Set the amount of memory

Also it would be better to emulate the slowest device from the genymotion list.

Comment: Oh ok, I was hoping that this would be an actual feature in Genymotion but I guess not. Thanks!